# Finding bearing of vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a program to calculate the resulting bearing of the addition of two vectors. Magnitude is not required.

The bearing is defined as the bearing of the tip of the second vector from the tail of the first vector.

The program crashes when I tried to run it. Also I'm aware that the functions are not returning expected results.

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

#define PI 3.14159265358979323846264338

using namespace std;

int _atan(int y, int x)
{
    if (x=0)
    {
        return 90*abs(y)/y;
    }
    else
    {
        return atan(y/x)*180/PI;
    }
}

int _bearing(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1)
{
    int bearing;
    bearing=90-_atan(y1-y0, x1-x0);
    if (bearing<0)
    {
        bearing=bearing+360;
    }
    return bearing;
}

int _vectorAdd(int m1, int b1, int m2, int b2)
{
    _bearing(0, 0, m1*sin(b1)+m2*sin(b2), m1*cos(b1)+m2*cos(b2));
}

int main()
{
    int m1;
    int b1;
    int m2;
    int b2;
    scanf("%d %d %d %d", &m1, &b1, &m2, &b2);
    printf("%d\n", _vectorAdd(m1, b1, m2, b2));
}
```

Comment: `int _vectorAdd(()` specifies a return type, but you didn't actually return anything there? Try `return _bearing(0, 0, m1*sin(b1)+m2*sin(b2), m1*cos(b1)+m2*cos(b2));`.

Comment: thx, I forgot to update code

Comment: You call that an update?

Comment: program simply crashes, I tried with 0 0 1 1, no hopes.

Comment: @vivien_pk `if (x=0)` doesn't do what you think it does. Should be `if (x==0)`

Comment: thx, program doesn't crash now. but 0 0 1 1 outputs 90, I was expecting 45

Comment: @vivien_pk We're not here to nanny you through every problem that pops up when another one was solved. Please ask a concise question containing a [MCVE], for all the rest step through your code using the debugger.

Comment: Rolled back to your initial version now, because this kind of moving targets doesn't help anyone.

Comment: The question of atan and atan2 are interesting ones. I remember atan burning me on calculation of vertical lines (since the slope is infinity, the divide by zero made my code crash)